# how to find element (html in html) in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKKib.png)
I'm facing a challenge when trying to locate elements within an HTML structure that contains nested HTML elements while using Selenium in developer mode. The issue is that when using a simple XPath, the higher-level HTML structure interferes with locating the XPath of the nested HTML elements. Since I have limited knowledge of HTML, I'm currently struggling to find a solution. Below is my Python code. I'm wondering how I should proceed...

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
test = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="header"]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a')

Traceback : selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

Comment: You need to switch to iframe first, if you want to access elements within it. See [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).

Answer (score 0):

An HTML nested in an HTML is an iframe or a frame. In selenium you have to switch to the frame before you try to interact with elements within it, see the [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/)

So first locate the frame, then switch to the frame, then you are able to interact with the elements within the frame.

```
frame = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//frame[@src='/companys/protns/']")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
test = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="header"]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a')
```

Keep in mind, if after this you want to interact with the outer HTML, you have to switch back to it. You can do this with the same switch_to function:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```